# Gmail will not render HTML email using PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I have been trying to get gmail to render the html contents of an e-mail I send to it, but it just gives me the complete text of the e-mail. When i send an e-mail to yahoo or my e-mail address at comcast.net, I have no problem seeing the html e-mail part. Gmail renders the whole thing including the boundary string. This is my code below:

```
//  Create a boundary string. It must be unique
//  so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash.
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
//  Define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n.
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From: \"" . $replyToName . "\" <" . $replyTo . ">\r\nReply-To: " . $replyTo . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
//  Add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-" . $random_hash ."\"";
$headers .= "\r\n";
//This is the plain-text part of the e-mail. This is what the recipient will see if they can only receive text-only e-mails.
?>
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<?php echo $plainMsg; ?>

<?php echo $mainSite; ?>
______________________________________________________

This e-mail is intended for the eyes of the recipient only. If you are not the
intended recipient, please send an e-mail to <?php echo $replyTo; ?> to inform us of
the mistake, and please destroy any and all copies of this e-mail.

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="cs" lang="cs">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#ADD8E6">
<tr>
<td><img src="<?php echo $mainLink; ?>/images/BF.gif" width="95" height="65"></td>
<td valign="top"><img src="<?php echo $imageLink; ?>" width="<?php echo $imageWidth; ?>" height="<?php echo $imageHeight; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
<?php echo $mailMsg; ?>
</font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<p>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
<a href="<?php echo $mainLink; ?>"><?php echo $mainSite; ?></a>
</font>
<br />
______________________________________________________
<br />
<br />
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">
This e-mail is intended for the eyes of the recipient only. If you are not the intended recipient, please send an e-mail to <a href="mailto:<?php echo $replyTo; ?>"><?php echo $replyTo; ?></a> to inform us of the mistake, and please destroy any and all copies of this e-mail.
</font>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#ADD8E6">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<font size="-2">All content, images, and data &#0169; Bright Futures 2009-2014.
<br />
All rights reserved.</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> --
```

When I send this e-mail,  I see the whole message not encoded. It shows me the boundary string and the html tags in the message. When I go to "Show Original" in gmail, I get the following:

```
Delivered-To: gsg1175@gmail.com
Received: by 10.182.23.6 with SMTP id i6csp32095obf;
        Wed, 19 Feb 2014 01:03:00 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.68.106.130 with SMTP id gu2mr924626pbb.59.1392800580001;
        Wed, 19 Feb 2014 01:03:00 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <gsg1175@p3plcpnl0157.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>
Received: from m1plded02-04.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net (m1plded02-04.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net. [64.202.189.17])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id ri10si3237317pbc.297.2014.02.19.01.02.59
        for <gsg1175@gmail.com>;
        Wed, 19 Feb 2014 01:02:59 -0800 (PST)
    Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of gsg1175@p3plcpnl0157.prod.phx3.secureserver.net designates 64.202.189.17 as permitted sender) client-ip=64.202.189.17;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of gsg1175@p3plcpnl0157.prod.phx3.secureserver.net designates 64.202.189.17 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=gsg1175@p3plcpnl0157.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
Received: from p3plcpnl0157.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ([184.168.200.188])
    by m1plded02-04.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net with : DED :
    id U92x1n01E44PGPL0192x1U; Wed, 19 Feb 2014 02:02:59 -0700
Received: from gsg1175 by p3plcpnl0157.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with local (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <gsg1175@p3plcpnl0157.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>)
    id 1WG33R-001P1W-8P; Wed, 19 Feb 2014 02:02:57 -0700
To: gsg1175@gmail.com,g.greenwell@comcast.net
Subject: Test E-mail
X-PHP-Script: www.yellowcas.com/sendemail.php for 107.4.20.247
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "Gregory Greenwell" <admin@yellowcas.com>
Reply-To: admin@yellowcas.com
CC: looking4unabq@yahoo.com
X-Mailer: PHP/5.4.23
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-8d0c53f7f76522e3a03197894d7e89fe"
Message-Id: <E1WG33R-001P1W-8P@p3plcpnl0157.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>
Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2014 02:02:57 -0700
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - p3plcpnl0157.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [267295 956] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - p3plcpnl0157.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: p3plcpnl0157.prod.phx3.secureserver.net: authenticated_id: gsg1175/from_h
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: /usr/sbin/proxyexec -q -d -s /var/run/proxyexec/cagefs.sock/socket /bin/cagefs.server 
X-Source-Dir: yellowcas.com:/public_html


--PHP-alt-8d0c53f7f76522e3a03197894d7e89fe 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit 

We will keep doing this until we get it right!

Why won't this work?

WWW.YELLOWCAS.COM
______________________________________________________

This e-mail is intended for the eyes of the recipient only. If you are not the intended recipient, please send an e-mail to admin@yellowcas.com to inform us of the mistake, and please destroy any and all copies of this e-mail.

--PHP-alt-8d0c53f7f76522e3a03197894d7e89fe 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit 


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="cs" lang="cs">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#ADD8E6">
<tr>
<td><img src="https://www.yellowcas.com/images/BF.gif" width="95" height="65"></td>
<td valign="top"><img src="https://www.yellowcas.com/images/brightfutures70.gif" width="520" height="60" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
We will keep doing this <b>until we get it right!</b>

Why won't this work?
</font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<p>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
<a href="https://www.yellowcas.com">WWW.YELLOWCAS.COM</a>
</font>
<br />
______________________________________________________
<br />
<br />
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">
This e-mail is intended for the eyes of the recipient only. If you are not the intended recipient, please send an e-mail to <a href="mailto:admin@yellowcas.com">admin@yellowcas.com</a> to inform us of the mistake, and please destroy any and all copies of this e-mail.
</font>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#ADD8E6">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<font size="-2">All content, images, and data &#0169; Bright Futures 2009-2014.
<br />
All rights reserved.
</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

--PHP-alt-8d0c53f7f76522e3a03197894d7e89fe--
```

I apologize for this being so long, but I cannot figure out why gmail is not displaying the html as html. I am using the php mail() function to send the e-mail. Every other e-mail client I have looked at renders the html just fine, but gmail just displays the underlying code in the e-mail. If ANYONE has ANY ideas, I would be very appreciative to hear them. Thank you for taking the time to review my code.

Comment: I have this exact same issue.  I have found out that X-AntiAbuse gets added by Gmail if your DNS entry is incorrect.  You can try http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/default.aspx to generate a correct SPF for your DNS entry. I am attempting this now.  If it doesn't work, I will add a bounty to this question.  If it does work, I will add what I did as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that you are using `\r\n`. Gmail doesn't render it anymore. If you replace it with `\n` , it should render at gmail.

I found it out before because i was freaked out that gmail didn't render it anymore. After a research i ended to [this blog](http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2012/php/getting-your-php-html-email-to-render-in-gmail/) which solved my 'little' issue.

Comment: I had looked at another post with a link to that exact page. I tried it, but it didn't work for me for some reason. I will try it again and post my results. Thank you for your response. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: I removed all the \r from the code, and gmail is still giving me the same result. This is frustrating me.

Comment: I found no evidence that it was the \r character in particular, but rather, any extra character before the \n, including spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things I did to resolve this problem for my system.

First: After some research as well as trial and error, I discovered that both Gmail and Thunderbird object to extra characters on the ends of header lines.  "\r" counts as an extra character, as do spaces.  I removed all "\r" characters from the whole thing just to be sure, because my code editor programs sometimes add them in while I am editing (I switch between different operating systems a lot).  To do this, you can use output buffers.

```
 ob_start();

 // all of your output here like normal

 $output = str_replace("\r","",ob_get_clean());
 echo $output;  // now your output has no "\r" characters
```

Second: I double-checked my MIME compatibility.  I happened to be missing a semicolon in one place but had an extra semicolon in another place, and I had extra spaces in a couple places as well.  You have unnecessary (and possibly sometimes not-allowed) quotation marks.  Here is a better way to do the headers so that you can clearly see where there might be extra characters.  By building the headers using an array and imploding with "\n", I guarantee that there are no "\r" characters or spaces on the ends.  You don't technically have to put variables into brackets `{}` but I always do so for clarity.

```
$replyToName = trim($replyToName);
$replyTo = trim($replyTo);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "From: {$replyToName} <{$replyTo}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: {$replyTo}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=PHP-alt-{$random_hash}";
$headers = implode("\n", $headers)."\n";
```

Third: Like you, I had DNS problems, which Gmail responds to by adding those `X-AntiAbuse` headers.  You don't want to see those, because they mean you are one step from the spam folder.  You should go to http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/default.aspx and follow the wizard to create a new SPF line for your DNS, then copy and paste what the wizard creates into your DNS entry.  If you have no idea what that means, call technical support for your web host and they should walk you through it.

Your current DNS:

```
v=spf1 a mx ptr include:secureserver.net ~all
```

What it should be is something like this:

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:107.4.20.247 ptr:secureserver.net a:secureserver.net include:secureserver.net ~all
```

By setting the "ptr" and "a" values to your email server (secureserver.net according to what you have pasted in your question), it lets Gmail and other receiving servers know that your email server is allowed to send email for you.  Including your site's specific IP address makes more email clients likely to believe you aren't a spammer.

By the way, you don't really need to do an md5 hash for your boundary string, and unlike in your comment, it doesn't have to be "unique," just not found in the body of the email.  Just put a string of letters and numbers that will definitely never appear in any email message, and you're fine.  Mine is "BOUNDARY456BREAK".  No one is going to write that in an email.